# flutter linking error with shared_preferences (ios)

Tags: flutter

I have this small project. It runs fine with flutter run. I builds fine with flutter build ios. But I can't go to Xcode and Product => Archive it.

it fails with :

```
ld: library not found for -lshared_preferences
```

I searched the web and I only found old problems that are not the cause of it. oh and flutter doctor -v is really happy with my setup,

```
• No issues found!
```

Comment: Make sure you're archiving it from the `Runner.xcworkspace` and not the `Runner.xcodeproj`.

Comment: sometimes I think I shouldn't work on pet projects while drunk... worst is that I'm sure I wouldn't even have noticed this morning

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Miguel in the comments, I opened (numerous times) the `Runner.xcodeproj` and not the `Runner.xcworkspace`, the workspace contains all needed libraries to be linked.